# Do Evolutions combine, for example Breath of Doom, Mecha Blast, and Claws of Steel?

Tags: king-of-tokyo-power-up

**Breath of Doom** is a Permanent Evolution that says:

> If you attack Tokyo, deal 1 damage to all other Monsters not in Tokyo.

**Mecha Blast** is a Temporary Evolution that says:

> Discard this Evolution to deal 2 extra damage.

**Claws of Steel** is a Permanent Evolution that says:

> Deal one extra damage on a turn in which you dealt 3 or more damage.

Starting with some poorly worded terms, **Damage** means: Lose [Heart]. It is unclear if Claws of Steel could be used in a 4 player game when Meka Dragon is in Tokyo and rolls a single [Claw] (since you are dealing 1 damage to 3 Monsters), or if it requires dealing 3 damage to a single source. I believe the correct answer is the latter.

**Can you reveal all three of these Evolutions during a turn where you attack Tokyo with a single [Claw], and if you do, what is the result?**

(Example: Do you deal 1 damage to Tokyo and with **Breath of Doom** 1 damage to all other Monsters, discard **Mecha Blast** to deal 2 more damage to Tokyo and all other Monsters, and **Claws of Steel** makes all Monsters take an additional 1 damage. **Final Result:** 4 damage to all other Monsters, or does the additional 2 damage from **Mecha Blast** not hit the Monsters outside of Tokyo?)

Comment: It sounds to me like Claws of Steel only counts and modifies the damage from attacks (claw dice). It's the use of "damage" rather than "damage to X". But who knows.

Comment: @ikegami, unfortunately there are too many examples where the cards and the rules are miss worded, or the terms are vague. [Firebreathing](https://iello.desk.com/customer/portal/questions/1270494-fire-breathing) for example, "Your neighbors take 1 extra damage when you deal damage", and iello's response "*Q:Does fire breating activate when you deal any damage?* A:Anytime you do damage wether by attacking or using an ability."

Comment: Their 2nd ruling ("yes, you can damage your neighbors regardless of their location") at the help desk is inconsistent with their [response on BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/743476/faq-in-english-answered-by-gabriel-iello-in-a-fren), "Fire breathing: your neighbours are the one around the table, so each time you attack, if your target is also your neighbour, he takes one extra damage."

Comment: I'm going to say that Mecha blast will probably only do 2 extra damage to one target. My guess is it will work together, but the final result will be atleast 3 + (rolls) to the creature in Tokyo and 1 damage to the surrounding players.

Answer (score 1):

If not specifically stated as with **Breath of Doom**, the term **deal X damage** always translates to

> Deal X damage to all target monsters and each monster that has taken damage from you this turn.

If you're in Tokyo, this means your target is all monsters outside of it. If you are attacking Tokyo, your target is all monster inside of Tokyo (Bay included). In case you have dealt damage to monsters that are not your target, they will also take extra damage from these modifiers.

And vice versa, the translation of "you dealt X or more damage" is

> All of the monsters that you targeted have taken X or more damage originating from your number of rolled claws, damage from cards and damage from power-ups.

So, if you're in Tokyo, you need to have at least dealt X damage to all monsters outside of Tokyo. This can be important because there are cards that affect only your neighbours.

This is how the total damage is counted after each effect in your example:

1. You roll a single **claw**.

   > **Total DMG: 1**: Only the monsters in Tokyo are affected
2. Use **Breath of Doom**.

   > **Total DMG: 1**: because the only monsters affected by **Breath of Doom** are the ones outside of Tokyo, hence not your target
3. Use **Mecha Blast**.

   > **Total DMG: 3**: At this point you've already attacked all other monsters, so all other monsters take extra damage. In case you wouldn't have played **Breath of Doom**, only the monster(s) in Tokyo would have taken 2 damage!
4. Play **Claws of Steel**.

   > **Total DMG: 4**: The same reasoning as in the previous step.

Answer (score 0):

@lyrion - You are correct.

This is the correct way to apply all these cards:

- A single claw roll will do one damage to the monster in Tokyo (**1 dmg**)
- then **Mecha Blast** will do +2 more damage  (**3 dmg**)
- **Claws of Steel** can then be played to add 1 more damage to the monster in Tokyo (**4 dmg**)
- Finally, **Breath of Doom** will do 1 damage to all the other monsters outside of Tokyo.

Unless the card specifically states that it affects all (*other*) monsters, it only modifies the damage to the monster in Tokyo.

---

If you were **in Tokyo** and attacking, you couldn't play **Breath of Doom**, but you *could* play the other two cards, inflicting **4 damage** on all monsters outside of Tokyo.

Comment: "Unless a card specifically states that it affects all (other) Monsters" Do you have any documentation to support that?  Also, I think you mean **whereever** you are not. You gave the example where when you are in Tokyo you do **deal 4 damage**.